# Sublime text 2: jslint plug-in missing /usr/local/bin/jslint

Tags: sublimetext2, jslint, sublimetext, sublime-jslint

I've got myself into a bit of a problem.
I left my computer at home and went to my summer home for a couple of days, when I return home and try to save files inside Sublime Text 2 I get this error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin/jslint'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Thankful for advice how to fix this :)

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/jslint` still exist, and is it executable?

Comment: i have no idea, ive been installin my plugins trough packet control, also im on a mac :P

Comment: yeah there is no file there :/

Comment: Was your jslint plugin working before?

Comment: yeah when i left home it did, i had problems before but fixed them by installing node :P

Comment: If you have Homebrew, you could try `brew install jsl` followed by `ln -s /usr/local/bin/jsl /usr/local/bin/jslint`. Otherwise you could download it manually (http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm) and then copy it to the same location.

Comment: dont know what homebrew is :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Jslint4Java or Node.js and its jslint module installed on your computer in order to make the plug-in work. Both of these projects provide jslint command.

For specific instructions to install Jslint4Java see:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/04/12/jslint-integration-for-sublime-text-2/

For specific instructions to install Node.js + jslint see:

https://github.com/reid/node-jslint

Also I recommend jshint (in SublimeLinter package) over jslint:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Comment: seemed my Node.js bugged out on me :) thanks for the reply tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Symlink the executable:
`ln -s /usr/local/share/npm/bin/jslint /usr/local/bin/jslint`

If you didn't use `npm install -g`, use `which jslint` to locate it

Comment: seemed my Node.js bugged out on me :) thanks for the reply tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into the **JSLint (with node) for Sublime Text 2** plugin at https://github.com/darrenderidder/Sublime-JSLint as an easy and straightforward alternative.